# Ionic AppRate show another popup

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried to show app rating screen in the android platform in ionic, but before the rating popup there's another popup.

Any idea where this popup come from?
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdqx4.jpg)

When I tapped on left null button/text it shown my apps rating
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD738.jpg)

Can I remove the first pop up?

Here's my AppRate code

```
constructor(
    private appRate: AppRate,
    public lgm: LoginModelProvider,
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public pf:GenFunctionProvider,
    public http: Http,
    public storage: Storage,
    private theInAppBrowser: InAppBrowser,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {
      this.banner = [];
      this.bannerPath = "";
      this.biller = [];

      appRate.preferences = {
        displayAppName: 'Solusipay',
        usesUntilPrompt: 2,
        storeAppURL: {
          android: 'market://details?id=com.solusipay.id'
        },
        customLocale: {
          title: "Would you mind rating %@?",
          message: "It won’t take more than a minute and helps to promote our app. Thanks for your support!",
          cancelButtonLabel: "No, Thanks",
          laterButtonLabel: "Remind Me Later",
          rateButtonLabel: "Rate It Now"
        },
        callbacks: {
          onRateDialogShow: function(callbacks) {
            console.log('rate shown:');
          },
          onButtonClicked: function(buttonIndex) {
            console.log('selected index: ', buttonIndex);
          }
        }
      }

      appRate.promptForRating(true);
  }
```

Comment: canu show full pledged code how ur calling this app rate thing

Comment: i just call it on constructor

Comment: canu post the full constructor code

Comment: updated for the constructor

Comment: try this appRate.promptForRating(false); instead of true

Comment: why set it to false? i'm new at this

Comment: did u checked with false?if not.. give a try and let me know

Comment: checked, and still appear that first pop up

Comment: okay cool, i thought according to the doc, false will works

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set **simpleMode=true** in appRate preferences

like below :

```
 appRate.preferences = {
    displayAppName: 'Solusipay',
    usesUntilPrompt: 2
    simpleMode : true, //this option is used to skip 1st popup
    storeAppURL: {
      android: 'market://details?id=com.solusipay.id'
    },
    customLocale: {
      title: "Would you mind rating %@?",
      message: "It won’t take more than a minute and helps to promote our app. Thanks for your support!",
      cancelButtonLabel: "No, Thanks",
      laterButtonLabel: "Remind Me Later",
      rateButtonLabel: "Rate It Now"
    },
    callbacks: {
      onRateDialogShow: function(callbacks) {
        console.log('rate shown:');
      },
      onButtonClicked: function(buttonIndex) {
        console.log('selected index: ', buttonIndex);
      }
    }
  }
```